# Java two dimensional output matrix

Tags: java, matrix

i want you to help me, this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Type your text: ");
        String text = input.nextLine();

        int counter = text.length();
        if(text.length()> 16)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: input text is greater than 16 characters");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            while(counter < 16)
            {
                text = text.concat("x");
                counter++;
            }

            char[][] k = new char[4][4];

            //int push = 0;

                                int push;

                                for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
                                    push = i;
                                    for (int j = 0; j < k[i].length; j++) {
                                        k[i][j] = text.charAt(push);
                                        System.out.print(k[i][j] + " ");
                                        push = push + 4;
                                    }
                                    System.out.println();                
                                }
        }

}
```

Now when i type: abcdefghijklmn , the output is:

```
a e i m
b f j n
c g k x
d h l x
```

this is perfect, when i print it looks like matrix. But now i have to print in other way:

```
aeim, bfjn, cgkx, dhlx
```

not as matrix but in line (with comma)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to achieve this? If so post the code you used to print it as a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `System.out.println();` with `System.out.print(", ");`

Answer (score 1):

just replace `System.out.println()` with `System.out.print(", ");` you don't need any condition and don't concat the character with a space, hope it works

Comment: You can look for the time I posted my answer it was before Qadir did it however thank you too

Comment: No, this would produce the string "a e i m , b f j n , c g k x , d h l x", and you would not have a new line char at the end.

Comment: Sorry, missed that one

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end, after the first set of nested for loops:

```
for (int j = 0; j < k[i].length; j++) {
     for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
              if (j == k[i].length - 1 && i == k.length - 1)
                   System.out.print(k[i][j] + ".");
              else
                   System.out.print(k[i][j] + ", ");
     }
}
```

---

The way that k is currently assigned values, it will print in this order:

```
aeim, bfjn, cgkx, dhlx
```

By reversing the nested for loops and modifying the print command, it will print:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, x, x.
```

This is, of course, assuming that you want to print the matrix and the list.
If not, then reverse the initial loop and change the way the values are assigned.

Comment: That would only produce the string "a, e, i, m, b, f, ..." without a new line at the end.